# Select the current date and other date in the phpunit selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I making the date format using jquery in the text box.
And want to know how can i select the date in the input box .

How can i set the value of current date format in the phpunit selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the php date function

```
 $startDate = date('Y-m-d');
 $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days"));

 $this->type('name=from_date',$startDate);
 $this->type('name=to_date',$endDate);
```